# how parallel operator changes the flow on subsequent stream elements?

Tags: java, java-stream

Executed below code

```
List.of(1, 2, 3, 4).stream()
    .map(
        integer -> {
          System.out.println(
              "Before parallel operator : " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + integer);
          return integer * 2;
        })
    .parallel()
    .map(
        integer -> {
          System.out.println(
              " After parallel operator : " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + integer);
          return integer * 2;
        })
    .forEach(
            integer -> {
          System.out.println(" For Each : " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + integer);
        });
```

Output:

```
    Before parallel operator : main : 3
Before parallel operator : ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19 : 2
Before parallel operator : ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-23 : 1
Before parallel operator : ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5 : 4
 After parallel operator : main : 6
 After parallel operator : ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-23 : 2
 After parallel operator : ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19 : 4
 After parallel operator : ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5 : 8
 For Each : ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19 : 8
 For Each : main : 12
 For Each : ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-23 : 4
 For Each : ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5 : 16
```

Apart from element 3 all other or ran in parallel?
Would like to understand behavior parallel operator on subsequent calls?

Where does the parallel operator kick in and how does the parallelism continue?

Comment: Your output not match the text in the print statements. Further, the thread named `main`  runs concurrently to the other threads named `…commonPool-worker…`, so element 3 *does* run in parallel like any other element. You have four elements being processed by four distinct threads. More parallelism isn’t possible.

Comment: @Holger, my question was more towards parallel operating affecting the pipeline than parallelism itself.

Comment: The answer has been given. The entire stream pipeline is either sequential or parallel. No excceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stream won't be processed until a terminal operation is called (such as `forEach` or `collect`), more to this in a bit. So, answering your question, "Where does the parallel operator kick in and how does the parallelism continue?".

**What the docs say?**

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) is clear about this matter:

> the stream's mode can be modified with the BaseStream.sequential() and BaseStream.parallel() operations. The most recent sequential or parallel mode setting applies to the execution of the entire stream pipeline

**A Little Demo**

Now consider the following piece of code (Pardon my `System.out`, it's for demo purposes). If we change between `parallel` and `sequential`, the entire pipeline changes, not only the subsequent operators.

```java
System.out.println("=== Creating stream s1 as 1,2,3,4");
var s1 = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4).stream();
System.out.println("s1 is parallel? " + s1.isParallel());

System.out.println("=== s2 results of applying map to s1");
var s2 = s1.map(integer -> integer * 2);
System.out.println("s1 is parallel? " + s1.isParallel());
System.out.println("s2 is parallel? " + s2.isParallel());

System.out.println("=== s3 results of applying parallel to s2");
var s3 = s2.parallel();
System.out.println("s1 is parallel? " + s1.isParallel());
System.out.println("s2 is parallel? " + s2.isParallel());
System.out.println("s3 is parallel? " + s3.isParallel());

System.out.println("=== s4 results of applying map to s3");
var s4 = s3.map(integer -> integer * 2);
System.out.println("s1 is parallel? " + s1.isParallel());
System.out.println("s2 is parallel? " + s2.isParallel());
System.out.println("s3 is parallel? " + s3.isParallel());
System.out.println("s4 is parallel? " + s4.isParallel());

System.out.println("=== s5 results of applying sequential to s4");
var s5 = s4.sequential();
System.out.println("s1 is parallel? " + s1.isParallel());
System.out.println("s2 is parallel? " + s2.isParallel());
System.out.println("s3 is parallel? " + s3.isParallel());
System.out.println("s4 is parallel? " + s4.isParallel());
System.out.println("s5 is parallel? " + s5.isParallel());
```

This will output the following:

```
=== Creating stream s1 as 1,2,3,4
s1 is parallel? false
=== s2 results of applying map to s1
s1 is parallel? false
s2 is parallel? false
=== s3 results of applying parallel to s2
s1 is parallel? true
s2 is parallel? true
s3 is parallel? true
=== s4 results of applying map to s3
s1 is parallel? true
s2 is parallel? true
s3 is parallel? true
s4 is parallel? true
=== s5 results of applying sequential to s4
s1 is parallel? false
s2 is parallel? false
s3 is parallel? false
s4 is parallel? false
s5 is parallel? false
```

Now when you call a terminal operator like `forEach` or `collect`, it will consider only sequential streams during processing, even though parallel was called in the middle. As the documentation states, the most recent applied mode is used for the entire pipeline.

**How is this useful?**

You may ask. It's possible to change the behaviour in the middle of the pipeline by "breaking" the pipeline with a terminal operator. For instance, taking your example, if we apply `collect` right after the first `map`, the first `map` will be executed sequentially, and then parallel will apply only to the subsequent operators but, in practice, this is now a different pipeline because everything was collected in the middle to a list.

```java
List.of(1, 2, 3, 4).stream()
    .map(integer -> {
        System.out.println("Before stream : " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + integer);
        return integer * 2;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .stream()
    .parallel()
    .map(integer -> {
        System.out.println("After parallel stream : " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + integer);
        return integer * 2;
    })
    .forEach(integer -> System.out.println("For Each : " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + integer));
```

This will now output something like:

```java
Before stream : main : 1
Before stream : main : 2
Before stream : main : 3
Before stream : main : 4
After parallel stream : main : 6
After parallel stream : ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-23 : 2
After parallel stream : ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5 : 4
After parallel stream : ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19 : 8
For Each : ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19 : 16
For Each : ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5 : 8
For Each : ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-23 : 4
For Each : main : 12
```

Notice how the first `map` is executed sequentially while the remaining operators are executed in parallel.

Observable streams implementations such as [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) got a different hang of this with the `observeOn` operator, but they are a totally different way of doing things as well.